# ui:inputDate not storing the field?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

learning some lightning, and am having this issue.

```
<aura:attribute name="cObj" access="global" type="Case" default="{'sObjectType':'Case'}" />
<div class="slds-form-element slds-hint-parent slds-m-left--large slds-m-right--large  slds-m-top--large slds-form-element__control" style ="font-weight:bold; color:rgb(84, 105, 141);font-size: .75rem;"> 
    <ui:inputDate label="Due Date"
                  aura:id="Due_Date__c" 
                  value="{!v.cobj.Due_Date__c}" 
                  displayDatePicker="true"
                  class="slds-input" />
</div>
```

so I see the field on the page, but when I click it and select the date, then click a different part of the page, the field goes blank. no issue using ui:inputText in the same format?

I doubled checked to see if Due_Date__c is a Date field too. Wonder if there is something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Locker Service you need to instantiate each field that you are going to use in your component which means the due_date__c needs to be set to '' in your attribute default declaration.

```
<aura:attribute name="cObj" access="global" type="Case" default="{'sObjectType':'Case','Due_Date__c': ''}"/>
```

Every field of the sobject that you want to use in your component needs to be instantiated like above.

Also Your attribute name is 'cObj' you have used 'cobj' in the ui:input date. There is a typo in the attribute name

Comment: hmmm I tried doing that and the due_date field behavior didn't change.

Comment: I think if you can elaborate or provide more clarity on 'click a different part of the page'.It would help if you can post code for the complete page.

Comment: As in click outside of the input box. will update my code, but its nothing fancy. just those input fields in a div.

Comment: Edited the answer. check the last line i think there is a typo in the attribute name you have used. 'cObj' should be used you have used 'cobj'

Comment: ah. that worked. ty!